# RadioGroup not updating bound value

Tags: extjs, radio-group, extjs7

I am using a `radiogroup` in my form, and I noticed that when I select one of the radio buttons, the value (bound value) is not updated.

Here's a small example:

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'container',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'formpanel',
        viewModel: {
            data: {
                myValue: 3
            }
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            label: 'This is the value of myValue:',
            bind: '{myValue}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Update myValue:',
            bind: '{myValue}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            vertical: true,
            label: 'Click a radio button:',
            bind: '{myValue}',
            items: [{
                label: 'One',
                value: 1
            }, {
                label: 'Two',
                value: 2
            }, {
                label: 'Three',
                value: 3
            }, ]
        }]
    }]
});
```

I created a simple `viewModel` with one data value: `myValue: 3`.  This is bound to all of the form elements: the `radiogroup`, a `textfield`, and a `displayfield`.

I'd expect that when I click one of the radio buttons, that the `displayfield` would update its value.  The `displayfield` value is updated when you type into the `textfield`, but the `radiogroup` is not updated.

It seems like the `radiogroup` is only using its bound value when it initializes, but it doesn't notice when it gets updated nor does it update it on its own.

What am I doing wrong?  Why doesn't the bound value get updated when I click on a radio button?

Here's an example over on Sencha Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/389i

---

UPDATE: I found a solution adding a `change` listener to the `radiogroup`.  Well, this fixes updating `myValue` wen you click on a radio button.  I'd need another listener to update the `radiogroup` when `myValue` is updated elsewhere (like in the `textfield`).

This works for my needs, but why should I need to add a `change` listener?  Why doesn't the `radiogroup` bind to `{myValue}` correctly?

```
listeners: {
    change: function(field, val) {
        let vm = field.lookupViewModel();
        vm.set('myValue', val);
    }
}
```

Here's a fiddle with this update applied: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/389k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue earlier this year, but I don't think I ever reported it to Sencha because I was using the Community Edition.  Anyway, from what I recall, I had tracked it down to some issue in the `getValue` method, believe it or not, and overrode that to the following ([Fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/389n&view/editor)):

```
Ext.define('MyOverride', {
    override: 'Ext.field.RadioGroup',

    getValue: function () {
        var value = this.callParent(arguments);
        var bind = this.getBind()
        var bindValue = bind && bind.value;
        if (bindValue) {
            if (Ext.isEmpty(value) && !Ext.isEmpty(bindValue.getValue())) {
                value = bindValue.getValue()
            }
            bindValue.setValue(value)
        }
        return value
    }
});
```

I'm sure this isn't the right method for this override, but it unblocked me for the time being.  Not sure if it's useful for you, but I wanted to share.

Comment: I think your solution is better. :) The main aim of the extjs overriding is to fix the bugs.

Comment: Now the question is, have either of you reported it as a bug?

Comment: Reported?) Idera has terrible user support. They have killed the framework mostly because of that.

Comment: Difference of opinion, I guess.  I've had quite a bit of success with Sencha Support, and definitely way more success than when they weren't owned by Idera.  I'll probably create one at some point then.

Comment: The company I work for has "premium support" with Sencha.  So, if I report it, maybe it can be forwarded to someone who can help.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, that'd be great if you created a Sencha Support ticket and referenced your question here on StackOverflow, so they have a history of what's going on.  It gets picked up by the next available support engineer, so they should be able to help.

Comment: @incutonez I did just that, and they gave me an "unofficial" fix :)  I posted that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've contacted Sencha support (of behalf of the company I work for; we have "premium support").  They said that there is already an opened bug report for this (`EXTJS-28689`) and they provided an "unofficial" override that fixes the issue.

```
Ext.define(null, {
    override: 'Ext.field.FieldGroupContainer',

    onGroupChange: function () {
        var me = this,
            newVal, oldVal, isValid;

        if (me.isConfiguring || me.isDestructing() || me.suspendCheckChange) {
            return;
        }

        newVal = me.getValue();
        oldVal = me.lastValue || me.originalValue;

        if (!me.isEqual(newVal, oldVal)) {
            me.lastValue = newVal;
            me.fireEvent('change', me, newVal, oldVal);
            isValid = me.validate();

            if (isValid) {
                me.publishState('value', newVal);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Fiddle with this override applied: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/38as

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you for following up with them and posting their answer here.

Comment: Stuff like this really makes me wish there bug tracker was public, or at least available to premium users.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in typing, the text field returns string and the radiogroup working with numbers.. for vise versa you will have to use dirty hack.. :-/

```
Ext.create({
    xtype: 'container',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'formpanel',
        viewModel: {
            data: {
                myValue: "3" // type string
            }
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'displayfield',
            label: 'This is the value of myValue:',
            bind: '{myValue}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            label: 'Update myValue:',
            bind: '{myValue}'
        }, {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            vertical: true,
            label: 'Click a radio button:',
            bind: '{myValue}',
            simpleValue: true,
            items: [{
                label: 'One',
                value: "1" // type string
            }, {
                label: 'Two',
                value: "2" // type string
            }, {
                label: 'Three',
                value: "3" // type string
            }],
            listeners: {
                change: function(radioGroup, newValue, oldValue) {
                    this.up('formpanel').getViewModel().set('myValue', newValue); // Dirty hack
                } 
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the `String` v `Number` thing.  In my actual project, that isn't an issue (they are all strings), it was just an issue in my example, so thanks for making that work :-)

Comment: As for the "dirty hack," that's what I wound up using in my project to solve this issue.  It just doesn't make sense that I would have to do that.  Could this be a bug in ExtJS?